# How can I remove the double slash after my domain using htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have a link like `http://example.com//1771-1A`, how can I remove the double slash after the domain address using `.htaccess`.

Comment: Let us know what you have tried

Comment: See my answer to [this question](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/102221/redirect-url-with-multiple-trailing-dots-and-trailing-slashes-using-htaccess) over on the ProWebmasters stack: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/102346/1243

Comment: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} ^.+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|swf|php|ico|txt|pdf|xml)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /manufacturer.php?manufact=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /manufacturer.php?manufact=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /partnumber.php?manufact=$1&partnumber=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /partnumber.php?manufact=$1&partnumber=$2 [QSA,L] `

Comment: @w3dk thanks. Your answer is working fine. http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/102346/1243

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/102346/1243) over on the Pro Webmasters stack:

```
# Remove multiple slashes at the start of the URL-path
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ //+
RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Reference:
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/102221/redirect-url-with-multiple-trailing-dots-and-trailing-slashes-using-htaccess